# How to open only some links in a iframe on the parent window

Tags: html, iframe, parent

i have an iframe on a page which opens a calendar application, in this application, I have some links that are of the app itself, while some other links should open in the parent window.

using: `<base target="_parent" />` makes all the links opens in the parent window, **but i would like only some kind of links** to target the parent window, not all...

is it possible to have a crossbrowser solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you don't really need the `<base>` tag. You could just use the the [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/a#attr-target) attribute on those links (`<a>`) you want to behave differently.

If you still want to use `<base>`, the target will be the one specified by `<base>` for those links without the `target` attribute.

For instance:

```
<base target="_self"></base>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_parent">Open SO in parent window/tab</a>
<br/>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" >Open SO in this window/tab</a>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j5FXQ/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just add a target parameter to a link you want to open in the parent frame? like `<a href="bla.html" target="_parent" />`

Answer (score 0):

With that snippet you open the link in the **parent**

```
<base target="_parent" />
<a target="_parent">your link open in the parent</a>
```

With that snippet you open the link in the **iframe** itself

```
<base target="_blank" />
<!-- that should even work without the bank -->
<a target="_blank">your link open in the iframe</a>
```

this is supported in all browsers

Comment: you can use target also on the `a` tag itself

Comment: added an example for the `a` tag